# How to test if the mean of a time series has significantly shifted at a certain point?

Tags: time-series, t-test, change-point

sorry if this has been asked before but I have searched the internet a lot but have not been able to find a satisfactory answer.

I have a time series (approximately 25 points) and I have implemented Binary Segmentation to detect a changepoint in the time series. My question is, how do I see if this changepoint is statistically significant? I.e I want to see if there is a shift in mean around that certain point in the time series. Ideally, I want to summarise this using a p-value. The standard t-tests do not apply I assume because the samples belong to a time series and hence the samples have some correlation.

I would be extremely thankful for any help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to CV.  I added the [tag:change-point] tag to help you identify threads likely to have answers: click through that tag to find them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-studied problem. Given the vagaries of time series data, there is no one-size-fits-all technique. If the purpose is to test whether there is a changepoint at a KNOWN location/time, a common method is the `Chow` test. But if the location of the changepoint is unknown, there are some methods like the Quandt Likelihood Ratio test and the `Pettitt` test for that purpose. All these procedures are available in R.

Further if the purpose is to explicitly test whether there is a shift in the mean, some model-based approaches may be more flexible. There are numerous packages available in the statistical program R for that, such as the `changepoint` and `bcp` packages. If somebody cares a Bayesian method, one choice is the `Rbeast` package developed by my group, available in `R`, `Python`, and `Matlab` (To indulge myself in self-prompting: https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast).  Here is a quick example in R

```
library(Rbeast)
data(Nile)                    # the annual streamflow of the River Nile
o1 = beast(Nile)              # A full Bayesian model
o2 = beast(Nile,method='bic') # based on the Bayesian information criterion
plot(o1)
plot(o2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the simpler case of independent data points, a simple two-sample t-test here would give too-low p-values because you choose the change point to create the pair of datasets with the largest possible t-statistic.

Suppose we generate a time series of 26 observations of $N(0, 1)$ observations, with no change points. If we split the data in two in the middle, the p-value will be $U(0, 1)$. But if we do binary segmentation then the p-value is likely to be lower, even though there are no change points in the data. I've simulated this happening 1,000 times in the code below

```
N = 1000
n = 26
set.seed(1)
# p_vals_half gives the p-values of t-tests from splitting the data into two equal parts
p_vals_half = numeric(N)
# p_vals_bin gives the p-values after choosing the split with binary segmentation and then computing the p-value for the resulting t-test
p_vals_bin = numeric(N)
for (i in 1:N) {
    data = rnorm(n)
    p_vals_half[i] = t.test(x = data[1:(n/2)], y = data[(n/2 + 1):n], alternative = "two.sided")$p.value
     # choose the change point that minimises the difference between the two data sets (and so minimises the p-value of a t-statistic)
     pvals_all = numeric(n - 3)
     for (j in 2:(n - 2)) {
      pvals_all[j - 1] = t.test(x = data[1:j], y = data[(j+1):n], alternative = "two.sided")$p.value
    }
    p_vals_bin[i] = min(pvals_all)
}

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
hist(p_vals_half, xlab = "P-Value", main = "Histogram of p-values from splitting in half")
hist(p_vals_bin, xlab = "P-Value", main = "Histogram of p-values from binary segmentation")
```

As you can see from the output, the straightforward t-test applied to a dataset generates a lot of spuriously low p-values. So even in the independent data case, you would need to take the fact that you are choosing the change point into account when you calculate the p-value.

[image: histograms]

I'd need more information about a model for the correlation structure of the data that you have to give a specific answer, but [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.01520.pdf), *Change point detection in autoregressive models with no moment assumptions* by
Akashi, Dette, Liu (2016), may be useful. Usefully, it cites a lot of papers on the topic of change detection in autoregressive models.