# Period cutoff in Chow test

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, exploratory-data-analysis, change-point, chow-test

I am using the Chow test to analyze structural change in time series data potentially caused by a significant event. Since each data point represents a day, the data is broken into two chunks:

Chunk 1: All data occurring before the event

Chunk 2: All data occurring on and after the event.

This is working fine, but I also want to analyze potential changes in the 30-day period following the significant event. In other words, I want to use a cutoff of 30 days rather than a single day, if that makes sense.

So far, I have tried to create a larger period cutoff by setting the beginning of the second chunk to 30 days after the event. This means the data is broken into two chunks:

Chunk 1: All data occurring before the event

Chunk 2: All data occurring 30 days later and beyond

To my understanding, this excludes data occurring in days 1-29. Assuming all of this makes sense, is this a valid way to apply the Chow test using a period cutoff rather than a single-day cutoff? If not, is there a better way to use a period cutoff? I came across this post, but it seems to deal with automatically detecting breakpoints rather than using *a priori* breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there are three ways to proceed:

1. What you're doing now, with the exclusion of the data from days 1-29, is ok. It will be under-powered (i.e. less likely to detect a change if there is one) just because you are throwing some data away. I don't know how much data you have outside of this period, if you have plenty of days either side of this period then it might be easiest just to leave it out.
2. Do a "sup"-Chow test: for each day in the period, do a Chow test, and then use the day that gives you the most significant result. Like in the start of the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/617338/how-to-test-if-the-mean-of-a-time-series-has-significantly-shifted-at-a-certain), treating the result of this like a standard Chow test will give you more false positives, so you will need to correct for this. You can get an estimate of the "sup"-Chow distribution by simulating from your estimate of the model parameters with no change. Let me know if you want more information on this.
3. This question is quite well-suited to a Bayesian approach. You could have a prior along the lines of $P(\textrm{no change}) = 0.9, P(\textrm{change on day 0}) = 0.1/30, \dots, P(\textrm{change on day 29}) = 0.1/30$, so that we are sceptical that there is a change, and if there is a change we do not have any prior information about where it will be in the interval. Our prior probability that there are no changes must be high otherwise we will definitely accept the change. With priors on the regression parameters $\beta$ as well, you could then compute the posterior probabilities $P(\textrm{no change} \mid X), \dots P(\textrm{change on day 29} \mid X)$ (where $X$ is your data), using
   $$P(\textrm{change on day t} \mid X) \propto P(\textrm{change on day t}) \int p(X \mid t, \beta) p(\beta) d\beta$$
   Let me know if you want more information on this.

Comment: Thank you, this information is very insightful. The first solution is obviously the easiest, but you're right that it's not as powerful as it could be. To ensure I understand you correctly, does the second solution mean conducting 30 Chow tests, where each test uses a day in the period, then taking the most significant result? I've used the Bonferroni correction when conducting multiple Chow tests, which should help reduce false positives. Solution 3 is intriguing. Would this mean applying Bayesian regression to the Chow test or something else?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes you would conduct 30 Chow tests and take the most significant result. Yes, the Bonferroni correction would work here - the p-values will all be dependent but the correction works even if that's the case. And yes, for 3 you would apply a Bayesian regression to the Chow test, you'd specify priors for the models with no change/1 change. I've integrated out the regression parameters in the formula above as I'm assuming you're more interested in the presence of a change than the regression parameters, but if you're interested in the estimating the change then you'd keep them

Comment: My data consists of multiple groups that could be affected by a significant event, so I am conducting the Chow test on each of these groups. I am doing the following: 1. For each group, perform 30 Chow tests. Once the 30 tests are run, perform the Bonferroni correction on the results of these 30 tests, then keep only the most significant result. 2. After each group has been tested, perform Bonferroni correction on the list of the most significant result of each group. Is this valid, or should I only be performing one correction? If only one correction is needed, where should it go?

Comment: Yes you would need the double correction that you described. For the second stage, where you're going through the separate groups, can I suggest that you use the Holm-Bonferroni correction instead of the regular Bonferroni correction? It has the same type I error rate but is uniformly more powerful than Bonferroni https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holm%E2%80%93Bonferroni_method . When you're just taking the single most significant result in step 1 then they are identical

Comment: Thank you for all the help you have provided so far. The second solution works, but how did you come up with it? Has this been done in practice before now?

Comment: Your problem reminded me of the approach in this paper: https://www.econometricsociety.org/publications/econometrica/1993/07/01/tests-parameter-instability-and-structural-change-unknown (and I referred to the test as a "sup"-Chow test based on the "sup" statistics in that paper) (sorry I don't have an open source link to the paper). I don't know if your exact problem has been done in practice before but it's related to the classic "determine if there's a change point" problem